# useState with condition inside a map

Tags: reactjs

I have the following state

```
const [thumbnail, setThumbnail] = useState({
  id: null,
  image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/200x100'
});
```

I can set the thumbnail in my `handleChange` function like

```
fetch(`/category/${id}`, {
  method: 'PUT',
  body: formData
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(response =>
    setThumbnail({ id: response.id, image: response.thumbnail })
  );
```

How can I get a thumbnail to display in a map like

```
{data &&
  data.map((category: CategoryInterface) => (
    image={}

<input
  accept="image/*"
  hidden
  ref={ref =>
    (inputRefs[
      category.id
    ] = ref as HTMLInputElement)
  }
  type="file"
  onChange={e => handleChange(e, category.id)}
/>
<IconButton
  onClick={() => handleClick(category.id)}
>
```

So basically I would like to display `category.thumbnail` by default and the placeholder if it doesn't exists, if I change a thumbnail it should only change the thumbnail for the one that I changed but if I set the `thumbnail` state inside `image={}` it would change all the thumbnails to the one that I set, is there a way to only change that specific thumbnail?

Comment: what is `data` ?

Comment: Data is a array of objects with id, name and thumbnail if there is a thumbnail, image takes a string (url) inside a component

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with the following

```
const [data, setData] = useState([] as CategoryInterface[]);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  fetch('/categories')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => setData(response));
}, [loading]);

// This part is called inside a map
setLoading(true);
// fetch
.then(() => setLoading(false));

// This part is inside a map
image={
  data.find(c => c.id === category.id)!.thumbnail ||
  'https://via.placeholder.com/200x100'
}
```